# Parse error: Unclosed '{'

Tags: php, html

Tengo un *parse error*, el cual no pude localizar. Supuse que es un error en las etiquetas de *PHP*, pero las puse de todas las formas, pero el error aún persiste. Gracias de antemano y saludos.

El error es el siguiente:

> Parse error: Unclosed '{' on line 64

Mi código:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID Talonario</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
            $tablaTalonario = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

            while ($filaTalonario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tablaTalonario)) {?>
            <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $filaTalonario['id_Talonario']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $filaTalonario['Nombre']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $filaTalonario['Fecha']?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php}?>

</table>
```

Comment: Prueba con la [sintaxis alternativa](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

El error que estás teniendo es: **`Unclosed '{'`**, y es que el cierre del `while` no está siendo reconocido aquí:

```
<?php}?>
```

Ese *totum revolutum* impide que PHP diferencie al mismo tiempo que estás a) abriendo un bloque PHP, b) escribiendo código PHP (en este caso `}`) c)cerrando un bloque PHP... O sea, abrir, codificar, cerrar ... ¡simplemente para terminar tu `while`!.

Si quieres seguir escribiendo mezclando bloques, entonces tienes que ponerlo así:

```
<?php } ?>
```

O sea: apertura de bloque, espacio, código, espacio, cierre de bloque.

### Recomendación

Yo te recomiendo que **evites lo más posible tanta mezcla de bloques, prefiriendo la concatenación de variables**.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  $html="
    <table>
      <tr>
          <th>ID Talonario</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Fecha</th>
      </tr>";
      
          $tablaTalonario = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
          $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

          while ($filaTalonario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tablaTalonario)) {
            $html.="
            <tr>
                    <td>$filaTalonario[id_Talonario]</td>
                    <td>$filaTalonario[Nombre]</td>
                    <td>$filaTalonario[Fecha]</td>
            </tr>";
          }
          $html.="</table>";
  echo $html;
?>
```

Aquí todo el código está en un solo bloque PHP. Hemos usado una variable `$html` para concatenar el contenido y al final la imprimimos.

Las ventajas son:

- Un código más claro y más limpio, menos propenso a errores.
- Un código fácil de depurar. Si quieres revisar tu variable, simplemente haces un `var_dump($html);` y verificas si hay algo mal.

NOTA: Convendría que verifiques si tu consulta trae filas, antes de lanzarte a crear una tabla sin saber si hay resultados. Pero eso ya lo dejo a tu criterio.

Comment: me imagine que venia por un tema de espacios...

Comment: @gbianchi esto no da error sin punto y coma: `<?php echo $filaTalonario['id_Talonario']?>` y el error es *`Unclosed '{'`* porque el cierre del while no se reconocía al no haber espacios para diferenciar la apertura/cierre de bloques.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano, voy a tener en cuenta su consejo sobre el uso de las variables, saludos.

Comment: @MatíasDiIorio te deje un comentario con varios enlaces que tenes que leer asi sabes como funciona el sitio. No es necesario agradecer, lo que hay que hacer es si la respuesta te sirvio, aceptarla. Tambien puedes votar positivamente todas las respuestas que te sirven, esa es la forma de decir gracias...